# Python method parameter evaluated after method invocation

Tags: python, parameter-passing, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

In the App Engine [NDB documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities), there is the following:

```
FlexEmployee.query(FlexEmployee.location == 'SF')
```

How is it that "FlexEmployee.location == 'SF'" is not first evaluated and the boolean result passed into query()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is that the base [`ndb.Property` class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model) overrides the `__eq__` method, so that it doesn't return a boolean but instead a FilterNode class that is passed into the actual query.

So, it *is* evaluated before `query` is called, but the result of that evaluation is not a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

The object returned by `FlexEmployee.location` defines a `__eq__` method that doesn't return a boolean - it returns a filter object that represents the expression "employee.location == 'SF'". The query method uses those filter objects that get passed in when it's constructing the query that it runs on the underlying storage.

The [property class also defines the magic methods](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#filter_by_prop) that enable you to use >, <, >=, <= and != in those expressions.